# PythonベースのGoogle App Engine で server side rendering用の server.jsを起動させたい

Tags: python, node.js, google-app-engine, angular4

PythonベースのGoogle App Engine で angular-universal を動かしたいと思っています。 npm run build すると distフォルダに Server Side Rendering 用の server.jsと server側のjsファイルなどが入ったserverフォルダができ、同じくフロント側のソースも出力されます。distフォルダに移動して gcloud app deploy とすると このpythonベースのアプリのdistフォルダへデプロイするんですが、server.jsを node server.jsで起動したいのですが、どうやってnode.jsで書かれたserver.jsをデプロイした先のdistフォルダから起動できるのでしょうか？　調べて見たところ gae はデプロイしたソースを編集したりコマンド打ったりできないそうで、デプロイして起動させるしかないみたいです。
node.jsで書かれたserver.jsを別途デプロイして起動させる感じなのか、yamlファイルがもう一つ必要になるのか？そのyamlファイルにどう書けばいいのか　など分からないとこだらけなのですが、どなたかわかる方お知恵をお貸しください。

今のApp.yaml は以下になります。

```
service: my-project
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets
- url: /.*
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```

npm run build:dynamic　コマンドを打って生成された /dist フォルダです 
    /dist
      |
       ー app.yaml
      |
       ー browser folder
      |      |
      |       ＿ assets folder
      |      |
      |       ー index.html
      |      | 
      |       ー ......
       ー prerender.js
      |
      |
       ー server.js
      |
       ー server folder
            |
             ーassets folder
            |
             ーmain.bundle.js 
            |
             ー .............

Comment: 本家の質問 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863301/how-can-i-run-server-js-on-python-based-google-app-engine-service

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine StandardはそれぞれのRuntimeの言語しか動かないので、Python Runtimeではnode.jsを動かすことはできません。
そのため、基本的にApp Engine Standardは、JSをそのままサーバサイドレンダリングするという手法を取ることは難しいです。
そのようなことをしたい場合、App Engine Flexを利用する, Cloud Function, Compute Engine,
 Kubernetes Engineを併用することになるんじゃないかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。GAEだとそれぞれのランタイム言語しか動かないのですね。 今はGAE Standardでpythonアプリが動いていまして、このフロント側がangularで書かれていてangularでもseoができるようにとangular-universalを導入しています。でこれを動かすためにはserver.jsをデプロイする必要があるのですが、google app engine flexible environment で新しくnodeのプロジェクトを作ってそっちにserver.jsをデプロイさせたとしてアクセスするURLはパイソンのアプリの方なのでそっちにアクセスしてそこからnode.jsアプリを見に行くようにすれば実現出来るということでしょうか？ それともpythonアプリもstandardではなくて最初からflexibleで作れば、pythonアプリの中でnode.jsアプリも動かせるということでしょうか？

Comment: 私はangularのサーバサイドレンダリングを行ったことがないので、なんともですが、私がやるのであれば、Cloud Functionsでサーバサイドレンダリングを動くようにして、botからリクエストが来た時にのみApp EngineからCloud Functionを実行して、レンダリング結果のHTMLを貰って返すという感じにすると思います。ついでに、1minぐらいGCPエッジキャッシュに乗せておくようにすると思います。